# When Using wai-aria how important is alt tag

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

If an image tag has to be inside the a tag, and has a sibling span, that displays the content which is same as the one in alt/title tags of a/img elements.

Without duplication of data

how can get accessibility using aria-labelledby attribute.

```
<a href="/project/image.jpg" title="photo caption" alt="photo caption">
 <img src="/image/thumb.jpg" alt="photo caption"/>
</a>

<span id="pc_1">photo caption</span>
```

I am hoping that this Question will help me to understand how aria specific attributes and regular html attributes play their roles in accessibility. Alt tag vs aria-labelledby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well for starters, your HTML is incorrect. The `alt` attribute is only valid on `<img>`, so you putting it on the anchor, is invalid. Second, I don't recommend using `title` because different assistive technologies deal with it differently. Third, `alt` text should be describing the image's meaning. Looking at the code, this link opens up a larger image of something, so the `alt` should be something like *view a larger version of the Mona Lisa*.

If you were writing this in HTML5, I'd modify it to:

```
<figure role="group">
 <a><img src="...." alt="Photo 1: view a larger version {a short phrase}" /></a>
 <caption>Photo 1: photo caption here</caption>
</figure>
```

You can check out [W3C's page on HTML5 techniques for text alternatives](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-alt-techniques/#sec1) for more reference/guidance.

**Replies to comments**
Sumit said

> "a short phrase" in our app is the "photo cation" itself. Or that duplication wouldn't matter for our users ?

Your app is doing it wrong, as I mentioned above. The alt should be describing the image if it doesn't have a proper title. The caption of it should give additional context, ex:

```
<figure role="group">
 <a><img src="...." alt="Photo 1: view a larger version the Mona Lisa" /></a>
 <caption>Photo 1: Sumit posing in front of 
 the <em>Mona Lisa</em> by da Vinci </caption>
</figure>
```

OR

```
<figure role="group">
 <a><img src="...." alt="Photo 1: view a larger version of a boy 
  holding a balloon" /></a>
 <caption>Photo 1: my son Johnny holding a red balloon from the 
  State Fair. It has to be 2' in diameter!</caption>
</figure>
```

Sumit said

> Also, my understanding was that image figure would prefer to have role=presentation. Is group better than presentation for some reason ? I'm sorry if I sound too naive with Accessibility

The `role="presentation"` is not correct here, as it removes syntax. So, making the `role="presentation"` in my *Mona Lisa* example, would make the output look like:

```
<>
 <a><img src="...." alt="Photo 1: view a larger version the Mona Lisa" /></a>
 <caption>Photo 1: Sumit posing in front of the
 <em>Mona Lisa</em> by da Vinci </caption>
</>
```

Comment: curious as to why the alt attribute should say "view a larger version of the mona lisa" instead of representing what the image's context is...i would think that would be the role of the anchor element. did you get that notion from the link you posted or somewhere else?

Comment: Looking at the OP's code, the link goes to an image file. If you put something in like image of ML, the person doesnt know if you're linking to the jpg or an in-depth analysis of the painting. Yeah you can argue people would figure it out, but telling them hey clicking this link may be a waste of time, shouldn't you tell them to save unneeded clicks?

Comment: my bad, i didn't really look @ the markup...that anchor sure looks lonely :) i was figuring there was some content there...href or maybe title attribute; text replaced by the image; something.

Comment: You mean my anchor? I dropped the `href` cause I was lazy basically, and said why I snipped @title

Comment: Ryan, sorry about the alt attr in anchor tag. My bad. Your solution helped answer another question in my mind. The Question was about adding assistive text specially for differently abled people. Tnx.

Comment: However, my doubt about Duplication of Photo Caption still persist since, "a short phrase" in our app is the "photo cation" itself. Or that duplication wouldn't matter for our users ?

Comment: Also, my understanding was that image figure would prefer to have role=presentation. Is group better than presentation for some reason ? I'm sorry if I sound too naive with Accessibility.

Comment: Summit, if this answer helped, please mark it as an answer. I will reply to the other parts in an edit to my answer.

Comment: I'm following http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-practices/ for learning aria. Its clear mostly. But when it comes to some roles(like presentation) i find it hard to distinguish which semantic web object deserves which aria role. or at what scope to use/differentiate role  main and application

Comment: When some radio input is inside a div, which in turn is inside that radio button specific fieldset. The role radiogroup, has to be given in the fieldset or on the div, or would the presence of fieldset and input field is enough over providing some specific roles. With roles, and aria-posinset things sounds more clear thought. I’m with lots of questions. Probably I didn't have reached more clearer doc, or may be my understanding is not enough. If you have answers or your choices on these conditions, or good web links to help me learn, please let me know.

Comment: Re ARIA: I will forward your comment onto the team. I do not work on the doc, but I know who does.

Comment: Re inputs: This is not related to your original question. I suggest you start a new question.

Comment: Shouldn't this rather be <figcaption> than <caption>? (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp)